# Trying to create a DOM based XSS example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security, xss

I'm trying to learn more about XSS prevention and in doing so, wrote some really simple javascript that I thought would allow XSS

```
<label id="searchLbl" for="search">Search</label>
<input id="search" autocomplete="off"/>

<div id="results"></div>

<script>
   document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
       if (code === 13) { 
           document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = document.getElementById('search').value;
            }
        });
</script>
```

This code works fine for taking what I type into the input field and showing it in the results div.  However, if I try typing in:

```
<script>alert("Failed");</script>
```

Both Chrome (v31) and Firefox(v25.0.1) refuse to set the div's innerHTML to the value. It appears that any string that has a < character in it, is truncated at the first instance of the character.

Using jQuery instead of JavaScript fails as I would expect.

```
$('#results').html($('#search').val());
```

What am I missing?

Comment: by the way, I know that the value of the input field is the correct full string (debugger). It's getting truncated somewhere around the assignment to innerHTML I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting JavaScript code in a `<script>` tag into the DOM doesn't cause the code to be executed. Inline `<script>` tags are only executed when the page is loaded.

Nothing is being truncated at the `<` character. You can see that if you try to inject HTML such as `<b>test</b>`

If you want to perform XSS using `<script>` tags, you would have to do something like make a request to the page with the HTML in a query string parameter, and then echo it onto the page with a serverside language like PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to emulate a DOM based XSS attack which is all client side.  I should not have to go back to the server for the DOM based attack.  At least that is my understanding.

Comment: Well, you could make an input box and then call eval() on whatever is typed in...

Comment: I changed the string that is entered into the input field to be:  
    `<div onmouseover="javascript:alert('failed!')">XSS Test</div>`  
this causes the DOM based XSS that I was looking for.